# Use value entered in UITextField

Tags: ios, xcode

How can I take an input value from the user with a text field and then use it to perform math functions in Swift?

I want to get a value from the user and then find the sine of that value.
Plus I want to take the input and covert it into radians.
Please help.

Comment: by taking the text, optionally creating an int or double or whatever out of it and then applying the `sin` to it. Where is the problem?

Comment: Actually I'm a beginner so can you provide me with some sort of example code?

Comment: like there is a button , textfield and a label so user enters a number in textfield presses the button and the sin of it displays on the label

Comment: Is your textfield added using storyboard and is it linked to your view controller already (as an outlet)? It would help us a lot by showing us what you have done already so we can help you from there.

Comment: i have an iboutlet for label and for textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you have the textfield as an IBOutlet. I've added a button to get the value:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func buttonPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let text = textField.text, value = Double(text) else { return }

    label.text = String(sin(value))
}
```

The reason I've used `guard` is because if text is `nil` or if it's not a `Double`, it will just `return`, having done nothing (which is what I want). This way you don't have to worry about unexpected crashes when trying to calculate the value.

Comment: Thanks a lot   just trying it

Comment: does it takes valuer in radians or degrees

Answer (score 0):

`let sinValue = sin(Double("2")!)`

is how you would process the string into a sin value

To get the text from the text field, you would need something like:

`let sinValue = sin(Double(someTextField.text)!)`

but you would first want to check that the text field had a value and validate that it was a number to prevent a crash.

Comment: thanks just trying it...

Comment: Ok now how to show it on a label

Comment: someLabel.text = "\(sinValue)"

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize Textfied
var textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(0, 0, 100, 100)) 
var sinNumber:Double = 0    

//Now in your header (where it says class X:subclass list)
//maybe something like class Viewcontroller:UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Add UITextFieldDelegate as above
Then you need to add the following function to determine when the user is done editing their TextField

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    sinNumber = getSinOfInput(textField.text)
}

func getSinOfNumber(numbers:String) {

    //If numbers is NOT a string full of numbers (it has characters), it should return nil
    var num = Double(numbers)
    if num != nil {
        //Do login here to find the sin
        num = ....
        return num
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}
```